# namespaces in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

How to use namespaces in C++ where it is accessible in different header files. Lets say I have this below:

```
// namespaces
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace first
{
  int var = 5;
}

namespace second
{
  double var = 3.1416;
}

int main () {
  cout << first::var << endl;
  cout << second::var << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and I want t use var variable from first namespace in another class... that is defined and implemented in another .h and .cpp file?

```
//server.h
    #ifndef SERVER_H
    #define SERVER_H
    class server{
       server();
    //blah
    };
    #endif SERVER_H

//server.cpp
server::server()
{
    first::var = 3;
}
```

is this possible to do it like this? When I try I get an error that says that my namespace is not defined. And if i put using namespace first in the .h or .cpp it says there is no namespace called first...

Comment: You should probably put those namespaces in a header file and include that where you need it.

Comment: DON'T DO THIS! Why are you drastically changing the question after 1 day? Ask a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides having the namespace in a header, you need to make the variable extern:

```
//header.h
namespace first
{
  extern int var;
}


//implementation.cpp
#include "header.h"
namespace first
{
   int var = 5;
}
```

If the variable is not `extern`, a symbol will be generated wherever the header is included, and you'll get linker errors.

If you don't want the extra header, you can just declare the variable as `extern` in the same namespace where you want to use it:

```
//server.cpp
namespace first
{
   extern int var;
}
server::server()
{
    first::var = 3;
}
```

**Note** some answers might claim that you should make the variable `static`. This is wrong, although it will compile, as then the variable won't act as a global. A copy of it will be created for every translation unit.

Comment: Since I hate doing that I have never learned about static making a copy for every translation unit. Thanks for the info! Also @CrazyEddie we all miss corner pieces of C++ here and there, don't be *too* harsh on people, eh?

Comment: @CrazyEddie I know, edited to reflect that just before your comment.

Comment: Though in implementation.cpp: I would do `int first::var = 5;`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I edited the question...I am now getting undefined reference errors...

Comment: @user1185853 and I edited back. Ask a new question, since it's a different issue.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore ok I asked a new question...could you look at it here...[new_post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535221/undefined-reference-to-namespaces-in-c)