# Undefined Reference to namespaces in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am getting an undefined reference when trying to use variables from my namespace. I created a header file and an implementation file with the namespace in it and am trying to use the namespace in  another file...

**EDITED:**

```
//first.h
namespace first
{
  extern int var;
  extern int multiplyVar(int);
}

//first.cpp
namespace first
{
  int var = 5;
  int multiplyVar(int mult)
  {
    return mult * var;
  }
}

//someOtherFile.h
#include "first.h"

//someOtherFile.cpp
first::var = 3;
int newVar = first::multiplyVar(3);

//error
undefined reference to  'first::multiplyVar(...)'
undefined reference to 'first::var'
```

**EDIT** Actual Code

```
//jFork.h
#ifndef JFORK_H
#define JFORK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace jFork
{
  extern int sockfd, newsockfd;
  int j_fork(string);
}

#endif //JWDSFORK_H

//jFork.cpp
namespace jFork
{
  int sockfd = 0, newsockfd = 0;

  int j_fork(string name)
  {
    cout<<"Preparing to fork: "<<name<<endl;

    int rv = fork();

    cout<<"Called fork(): "<<name<<endl;

    switch(rv)
    {
    case -1:
        cout<<"Exiting..."<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    case 0:
        if(sockfd)
        {
            cout<<"Closing sockfd: "<<name<<endl;
            close(sockfd);
            sockfd = 0;
        }

        if(newsockfd)
        {
            cout<<"Closing newsockfd: "<<name<<endl;
            close(newsockfd);
            newsockfd = 0;
        }

        break;
    default:
        cout<<"Preparing to sleep: "<<name<<endl;
        sleep(1);
        cout<<"Woke up from sleep"<<name<<endl;
        break;
    }

    return rv;
  }
}

//server.cpp
int pid = jFork::j_fork(name);
```

Comment: did you define those things within the namespace in quesion in the .cpp?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "first.cpp" won't compile. Did you copy-paste your code, or is this a sorta-kinda-pseudocode?

Comment: @Robᵩ its sort of kinda psuedocode...

Comment: @PlasmaHH i just did that per the answer below but its still getting the undefined reference errors

Comment: Copy & paste your actual test code. “Kinda” pseudo-code is not useful, and if your problem is in the parts you edited, but didn't ask the compiler, you're wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Just drop the externs surely? What value are they adding? You already have them in a namespace.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig just added actual code

Comment: @Component10 when I delete the extern all the undefined references go away (with the exception of the one for the function call) and I get errors with multiple definitions (redefinitions)

Comment: @user1185853: And is it the same namespace name, or did you chose a different for your cpp?

Comment: @PlasmaHH was an error copying...but they are the same

Comment: @user1185853: Try taking the `extern`s out and replacing `int var = 5;` in your first.cpp with `var = 5;` as it looks as if you're *declaring* var twice. I'm guessing you added the `extern` to try to get round the original undefined references?

Comment: I don't think that is the actual code you are using. That `jFork.cpp` wouldn't compile, because `string` is not defined; you don't have any `#include`s in there. I really meant posting actual, complete files, but of the stripped-down test code you are actually using, code that does not contain anything not related to the question. Yes, it is worth creating that kind of test code.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig this is the actual code that im using except in my code I #include <string.h> and i changed that per a response that it should be #include <string>

Comment: How does it compile since you don't include <iostream>? Also, `int pid = jFork::j_fork(name);` is wrong. What is `name`?

Comment: @user1185853 : Look at http://sscce.org for information about creating and presenting a helpful testcase.

Comment: … and have `using namespace std;` (incidentally, doing that in a header is flagged by most code guidelines I'm aware of, but that's a different issue).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore that is in another file that is about 200 lines long thats why i didnt include it **name** is some string that gets into the function from that class that calls jFork::j_fork()...and i just added #include<iostream> must have overlooked that - but it doesnt make a difference...

Comment: Ok, if you follow all these steps, all that's left is the compiler. It's broken. (but my guess is that you're either not compiling that file or not linking against it)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore if its in my project why wouldnt it be compiling - (im using codeblocks running on  xming compiling with gnu gcc compiler doubt that its broken)

Comment: @Component10 that still gives me the multiple definition error

Comment: @user1185853 dropping extern is not the way. I posted the code because it is correct. I proved that it's correct in ideone.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore when you said the `int pid = jFork:j_fork(name)` was wrong - what would be the correct way to reference that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note no `extern` for function declrations and defining the symbols in the namespace in the implementation file.

```
//first.h
namespace first
{
  extern int var;
  extern int multiplyVar(int);
}

//first.cpp
var = 5;
extern int multiplyVar(int mult)
{
  return mult * var;
}
```

Should be

```
//first.h
namespace first
{
  extern int var;
  int multiplyVar(int);
}

//first.cpp
namespace first
{
   int var = 5;
   int multiplyVar(int mult)
   {
     return mult * var;
   }
}
```

Comment: still getting the undefined reference...I am supposed to do #include "first.h" or using namespace first (error says no namespace named first)?

Comment: @user1185853 yes you need to include `first.h` where you want to use it.

Comment: I did still getting undefined references everywhere i use the variables and functions

Comment: @user1185853 are you sure you're compiling `first.cpp`? Are you sure it's exactly the way I posted it, or did you change anything?

Comment: I just checked again...its like it is here - and the .cpp is a part of my project - I believe it is compiling...

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig right i just edited the original question adding the namespace stuff to first.cpp

Comment: @user1185853 http://ideone.com/52pgS it compiles and links just fine. Are you **sure** you're compiling `first.cpp`? And you're linking against the object file?

Comment: @user1185853 also, note that it's `<string>` not `<string.h>`.

Comment: I ended creating a new project and basically starting from scratch...everything ended up working...

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
extern int first::multiplyVar(int mult)
```

Your definition is in the global namespace.

You could also wrap all the definitions in the CPP file in a `namespace` block, but my preference is to not do it this way.

Comment: The declaration is already in a namespace, why add another one? Apart from the `extern` being rather pointless for a function declaration …